# Did I write this query correctly?

Tags: sql-server

I'm given the question[image]

My solution is

```
USE Finances

CREATE TABLE Account 
    (AccountID varchar(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     AccountName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     AccountAddress varchar(30) NULL,
     AccountCity varchar(25) NULL, 
     AccountState char(2) NULL,
     AccountZip varchar(10) NULL,
     AccountPhone varchar(14) NULL)

CREATE TABLE Transactions
    (TransactionID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
     AccountID varchar(25) REFERENCES Account (AccountID),
     TransactionDate smalldatetime NOT NULL,
     TransactionAmount money NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE Register
    (RegisterID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
     TransactionID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Transactions (TransactionID));
```

Part of the reason I'm confused is because I don't completely understand the primary/foreign key relationship. Like I look at the question and say, ok the registerID will be the single/unique ID to seperate every account from each other. But I see that there's a TranasctionID in the same table. And that TransactionID is a foreign key to the TransactionID in the transaction table. So does that mean whenever a new tranasctionID is added there is a corresponding RegisterID. Like whats the point of the Register ID?? And did I write this query correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The only issue in you script is your column "AccountID" in table "Transactions" is creating with allowing NULL and "TransactionAmount" is NOT NULL where as it should allow NULL. Other wise I found the tables are creating with appropriate type and relation as instructed.

Regarding your confusion, I am confused too thinking about the purpose of table "Register". As per instruction, yes it will create a new row every time a new transaction take place. As registerId is a PK, with each transaction a new PK will generate. But the question is why a new RegisterId is required for each TransactionID? If RegisterId is referring to other table for a transaction details, it can be easily use the TransactionID directly as both TransactionID and RegisterId are unique (PK).